# Оптимизация и объединение функций

Tags: php, массивы, функции, оптимизация, foreach

Ниже расположен мой г*но код, в котором имеются две функции, которые делают по порядку:
**Pregsplit**

*Здесь просто стилизуем каждую букву и задаём атрибуты для обёртывающего тега*

1. Берёт две входные переменные;
2. Обёртывает их в тег span;
3. Далее переводим всё в верхний регистр;
4. Разбиваем строку на подстроки;
5. В *массиве строк* все подстроки разбиваем на буквы;
6. В *массиве букв* каждую буквы выделяем в обозначение теги.

**Postar**

*В данную функцию вводим ключ переменной $_POST*

1. Проверяем пуста ли переменная указанного ключа;
2. Проверяем соответствует ли переменная условию;
3. Если соответствует, то:

   - Форматируем дату;
   - Выводим отдельно день, месяц и год и стилизуем при помощи функции **Pregsplit**;
   - Объединяем стилизованный день, месяц и год в одну переменную и выводим значение *$value*
4. Если не соответствует, то:

   - Стилизуем при помощи функции **Pregsplit**;
   - Выводим значение *$value*

**Вопрос:** Я никак не могу додуматься до того, как бы эти две функции объединить в одну так как по сути я использую только функция **Postar**. Отдельно функцию **Pregsplit** я не использую

```
<?php
function pregsplit($name, $other) {
    echo '<span'.$other.'>';
    $name = mb_strtoupper($name, 'UTF-8');
    $name = explode(' ', $name);
    foreach ($name as $names) {
        $names = preg_split('//u', $names, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        foreach ($names as $value) {
            echo '<span class="for-span"><span>'.$value.'</span></span>';
        }
    }
    echo '</span>';
}

function postar($name) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$name])) {
        if ($name == 'birthday' || $name == 'pas_date' || $name == 'pas_srok' || $name == 'visa_date' || $name == 'visa_srok') {
            $value = new DateTime($value);
            $value_d = $value->format('d');
            $value_d = pregsplit($value_d, ' style="margin-right:14mm"');
            $value_m = $value->format('m');
            $value_m = pregsplit($value_m, ' style="margin-right:6mm"');
            $value_y = $value->format('Y');
            $value_y = pregsplit($value_y);
            $value = $value_d.$value_m.$value_y;
            echo $value;
        }
        else {
            $name = pregsplit($_POST[$name]);
            echo $name;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: А зачем Вам в одну объединять?

Comment: @Чад хороший вопрос. Главный вопрос состоит в быстродействии. Я не знаю насколько данные функции оптимизированы, и знаю, что их можно сократить соединив вместе(возможно я ошибаюсь). И ещё для красоты и понимания как делать адекватные функции. Хотя понятие адекватная функция мне не особо знакома, но мне кажется я иду в верном направлении)

Comment: Учитывая, что это интерпретатор а не компилятор, вынос дублирующего кода, в отдельную функцию наоборот придаст ускорение.

Comment: и ускорить, думаеться мне можно конструкцию вида: `($name == 'birthday' || $name == 'pas_date' || $name == 'pas_srok' || $name == 'visa_date' || $name == 'visa_srok')` в что то типа `array_search(arrya('birthday','pas_date',...), $name)`